Org mode: How do I create links with spaces in the directory names?
It seems that I can have links where there are spaces in the filenames, but not in directory names. For example:
[[file:FC2/VA/Veterans_Payment_Statement/22-03-05 VPS.jpg][22-03-05 VPS.jpg]]

works, but using spaces in the directory like this:
[[file:FC2/VA/Veterans Payment Statement/22-03-05 VPS.jpg][22-03-05 VPS.jpg]]

or using using quotes like
[[file:FC2/VA/"Veterans_Payment_Statement"/22-03-05 VPS.jpg][22-03-05 VPS.jpg]]

or
[[file:FC2/VA/'Veterans_Payment_Statement'/22-03-05 VPS.jpg][22-03-05 VPS.jpg]]

fail. Note that there is a space in the filename. That seems to work OK, but spaces in directory names are a problem. So how do I format the link so that I can have spaces in the directory name? Of course I have lots of directories with spaces so this is a big deal for me.

How does the second link fail? Do you get some error message? And what is your Org mode version (M-x org-version)? FWIW, assuming that everything exists and is readable, the second link works fine for me.
